# Eclipse JDT: How do I auto-move dependencies of a statement as well, while moving the statement

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I have following functions-

```
void called(PassedObj obP){
    A obA = new A(pOb);
    B obB = new B(obA);
    obB.randomFunc();
    ...
}

void caller(){
    PassedObj obP= new PassedObj();
    called(obP);
}
```

Using Eclipse JDT, is it possible to automatically figure out all the dependencies of the obB and auto-move them to the caller function?

I want to refactor these functions to look something like-

```
void called(B obB){
    obB.randomFunc();
    ...
}

void caller(){
    PassedObj obP= new PassedObj();
    A obA = new A(obP);
    B obB = new B(obA);
    called(objB);
}
```

In general, is it possible to move a statement to another function so that all the dependencies of the statement are also moved(copied) to the new place?

Answer (score 1):

No, but the good news is that you can achieve what you want with JDT albeit differently than what you are asking.

Here you should extract the method `called(B)`:

```
void called(PassedObj obP){
    A obA = new A(pOb);
    B obB = new B(obA);
    called(obB);
}

void called(B obB){
    obB.randomFunc();
    ...
}

void caller(){
    PassedObj obP= new PassedObj();
    called(obP);
}
```

And then inline the method `called(PassedObj)`:

```
void called(B obB){
    obB.randomFunc();
    ...
}

void caller(){
    PassedObj obP= new PassedObj();
    A obA = new A(pOb);
    B obB = new B(obA);
    called(obB);
}
```